# How to add a html file contents as a child element in another html using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have two html files with me. I want to add one file contents as div element content in another file using javascript. 
PFB the code snippets I used.

1.Without Ajax

```
file = fopen(getScriptPath("report"), 0);
file_length = flength(file);
content = fread(file, file_length);
document.getElementById("secondary").innerText = content;
```

2.Ajax call

```
var reader = new FileReader();
function readText(){        
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (e) {  
   var output=e.target.result;
   document.getElementById('secondary').innerHTML= output;
 }
reader.readAsText('report');
```

Comment: Can you use jQuery? It makes this very easy

Comment: A bit of advice:  Don't put "Please help me out" or "Early response is appreciated" in your posts.  This is especially true when your post doesn't say what you have tried, and shows no effort from you to solve your own problem.  This site isn't where people do your work for you.  It's where people answer questions that everyone can learn from.

Comment: I wonder how people manage to get that amount of reputation, asking questions like these.

Anyway, what are you doing with the 2 HTML files?

Comment: All his questions have high voting, strange!

Comment: when you say having with you? next to you? is it iframes? is it two separate files?

Comment: @Brad Thank you for your suggestion. I should have added my research done in this query. But I dont have enough time, So I thought I could get answer.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Please see my previous questions so that you will get an idea, how I got the reputaion. As stated in the above comment I dont have much time to explain the question. See the edited question.

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie Yes, all my previous questions are high rated. I provided my findings in those questions. I do agree in this question I didn't provide my findings. Please see my edits to question.

Comment: @themis I have two static html files with me.

Comment: @Pekka웃 yes I can use jquery. But I am new to Jquery.

Comment: @P.Muralikrishna, If you don't have time to ask a proper question, then why should we waste our time in trying to figure out how to answer you?  If you don't have time, then perhaps you should hire a programmer to do the work for you.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what other libraries are you using to have functions like `fopen` in Javascript? These things are important to know as they may interfere or provide an easier method of achieving a task.

Answer (score 1):

To simplify the answer, I will use jQuery to do all of the heavy lifting.

**jQuery + iFrame**

```
var $iframe = $('<iframe>').attr('src','YOUR_OTHER_PAGE');
$('body').append($iframe);
//Note: Will need styling etc to place the iFrame where you want it
```

**jQuery + AJAX**

```
$('body').load('YOUR_OTHER_PAGE');
```

[jQuery Documentation for .load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Honestly though, I would try and avoid both. If you can have the HTML content added into the first page server-side (so in PHP, that might be using the `include` function), that would be the best.